# Creating Multiple excel books with xlwings - computational requirements

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

Just a (hopefully) quick question regarding creating and working on multiple woorkbooks at once.

Is there a way to reduce computational burden when using xlwings? If i want to create say ten workbooks at once then save them at a later time the CPU usage begins to be quite high.

My use case would be a web app which generates excel workbooks, so there can be quite a few workbooks being created at any one time.

From what I have read, xlwings by design must use an instance of excel, so I am assuming my use case will require an alternative such as openpyxl.

Comment: That's right, for the use case of a web app creating Excel files, only the options that write files directly are advisable, i.e. instead of xlwings use openpyxl, xlsxwriter or xlwt

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for the prompt reply.